# rails 3 app using rmagick starts using passenger standalone but fails using passenger through apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, rmagick

I'm working on a Rails 3 app that includes rmagick and I'm able to start and run it successfully using WEBrick and Passenger Standalone. However, when I try running the app using Passenger within Apache, I get the following error:

> dlopen(/Users/20217633/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.bundle,
>   9): Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
>   Expected in: /usr/local//lib/libjpeg.8.dylib in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
>   - /Users/20217633/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.bundle

Is anyone familiar with this problem?

**=== UPDATE ===**

Below is a copy of my httpd.conf:

```
SetEnv PATH /usr/bin:/usr/local/bin

LoadModule passenger_module /Users/20217633/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/passenger-3.0.2/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
LoadModule upload_progress_module modules/mod_upload_progress.so
PassengerRoot /Users/20217633/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/passenger-3.0.2
PassengerRuby /Users/20217633/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/ruby

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /Users/20217633/apps/github/project/public

    PassengerLogLevel 3
    RackEnv development
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache worker processes don't run as a normal user, the environment is scrubbed and won't have things like path.

I bet you're loading a different/incorrect version of ImageMagick under Passenger/Apache.

You should be able to fix this by manually setting your PATH in your passenger/apache conf:

```
SetEnv PATH /usr/bin:/path/to/correct/image_magick
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @winfield - I tried adding the path as you can see in my edits above but to no avail. would you please verify that my httpd.conf matches your suggestion? _which convert_ returns */usr/local/bin/convert*

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a symlink is broken, I found something in [this forum](http://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=34995#p101661)

delete the symlinks "libpng.dylib" and "libjpeg.dylib" in `"<installation directory>/lib/"`

Create new symlinks to the right libs.

```
ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPNG.dylib /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libPNG.dylib

ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libJPEG.dylib
```

I have no Mac rigth here, but first **i would verify** that the origin of the symlink exist, i hope this will solve your problem.